# Way to get rid of copy-pasted code in a method

Tags: java

I'm creating a visual representation of a sphere using gpdraw and pen.drawOval(num1,num2) with num1 and num2 having an increment operator of 5. The way I'm creating this has me copy-pasting the same 2 lines of code 40 times. This hardly seems efficient or professional in anyway. How can I repeat these lines an exact number of times or repeat the method an exact number of times?

## DrawSphereTester Class

```
public class SphereDrawTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SphereDraw draw = new SphereDraw();
        draw.draw();
    }
}
```

## DrawSphere Class

```
import gpdraw.*;

public class SphereDraw
{
    //Instance variables
    public SketchPad Paper;
    public DrawingTool pen;

//Constructor
public SphereDraw()
{

    Paper = new SketchPad(800, 800);
    pen = new DrawingTool(Paper);
}

public void draw()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 200;

    pen.drawCircle(100);

    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, it's time to learn about loops!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
    pen.drawOval(num1,num2);
    num1 += 5;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tested this, but it looks solid =)

Comment: Thank you, had an idea of some kind of loop. Being new to coding has it's downsides, like having no knowledge of howto do simple things like create a for loop. This is going to help me a lot in the future, I can already tell.